# What is spatial correlation and spatial convolution?

Tags: image-processing, convolution, correlation, digital, spatial

What does the term `spatial correlation` and `spatial convolution` mean with respect to *digital image processing* ?

Comment: While *Spatial Convolution* is certainly an operation done over signals defined in Spatial Indices *Spatial Correlation* can be interpreted either as an operation (Correlation, as a flipped convolution) or a property, namely signal which is values have spatial correlation one with each other. What do you mean? Only as operations?

Answer (score 3):

These terms exist mainly for historical reasons. In signal processing the signal is a one-dimensional function of time.  So people talk about the *time domain* vs. the *frequency domain*.  On the other hand, in image processing you are looking at a 2D function of $x$ and $y$, and there is no notion of time.  Instead your are talking about *spatial frequencies*.  Hence, *spatial correlation* and *spatial convolution*.

Typically, in image processing you simply talk about *convolution* and *correlation*.  The term *spatial* usually shows up when 2-D convolution and correlation are introduced to people with background in signal processing.

Comment: If you could please explain these terms extensively. I don't have a feel of what do these terms mean

Comment: To get a feel for those terms you would need to read up on Fourier transform.